# I can't save two datetimes at the same time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, datetime, simple-form, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I'm trying to submit a form and have all of my data save to the database, but one column does not get saved. I have a form where you set a start_at datetime and and end_at datetime. When I click the create button it appears that both pieces of data are being sent, but only one is being saved to the database. At first neither would save, and I don't know what I've done to get one to save.

I'm using Rails 4.2.5.1, ruby 2.3, postgres 9.3, simple_form and bootstrap3-datetimepicker.

Below is the code related to the issue, if anyone is able to figure out what I'm doing wrong I'd appreciate the help.

_form.html.erb

```
<div class="form-group">
    <%= simple_form_for shallow_args(current_user, @image) do |f| %>
    <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
    <%= f.label            :file %><br>
    <%= f.attachment_field :file, direct: true %>

    <div class="row">
        <%= f.collection_check_boxes :category_ids, Category.all, :id, :name do |cb| %>
        <% cb.label(class: "checkbox-inline input_checkbox") {cb.check_box(class: "checkbox") + cb.text}%>
        <% end %>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <%= label_tag :start_at, 'StartTime' %>
                    <div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker">
                        <%= f.text_field :start_at, class: 'form-control' %>
                        <span class="input-group-addon">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <%= label_tag :end_at, 'End of Image run' %>
                    <div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker1">
                        <%= f.text_field :end_at, class: 'form-control' %>
                        <span class="input-group-addon">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="actions">
        <%= f.submit %>
    </div>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

assets/images.coffee

```
$(document).on "turbolinks:load", ->
$('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker()
$('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker()
```

images_controller.rb

```
# GET /images/new
def new
    @image = current_user.images.build
end
# POST /images
# POST /images.json
def create
    @image = current_user.images.build(image_params)
    respond_to do |format|
        if @image.save
            format.html { redirect_to @image, notice: 'Image was successfully created.' }
            format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @image }
        else
            format.html { render :new }
            format.json { render json: @image.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        end
    end
end

def image_params
    params.require(:image).permit(:file, :start_at, :end_at, category_ids: [])
end
```

Parameters being passed copied from my server output:

```
    Started POST "/users/1/images" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-07-15 14:46:59 -0400
Processing by ImagesController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"87O2h62EXrLtJ084/ydt5N7PzjQ+7ezh2xPk0E14VwtZyA/gb9P6yDExfGYdonfZXSDbKnNX7VExk/80Y+7n9w==", "image"=>{"file"=>"{\"id\":\"c4b7b6c51dd3b083e359e4fa2ba9da2023bef8597c1175a2f2f235c31018\",\"filename\":\"c8f98ef4b2acc1754bab905ee8d61afe.jpg\",\"content_type\":\"image/jpeg\",\"size\":33018}", "category_ids"=>["2", "5", ""], "start_at"=>"07/23/2016 2:46 PM", "end_at"=>"10/08/2016 7:46 PM"}, "commit"=>"Create Image", "user_id"=>"1"}
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  Category Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories" WHERE "categories"."id" IN (2, 5)
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  Category Exists (0.4ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "categories" WHERE ("categories"."name" = 'Funny' AND "categories"."id" != 2) LIMIT 1
  Category Exists (0.3ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "categories" WHERE ("categories"."name" = 'Cool Stuff' AND "categories"."id" != 5) LIMIT 1
  SQL (0.6ms)  INSERT INTO "images" ("file_id", "end_at", "user_id", "width", "height", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7) RETURNING "id"  [["file_id", "117118"], ["end_at", "2016-08-10 19:46:00.000000"], ["user_id", 1], ["width", "564"], ["height", "564"], ["created_at", "2016-07-15 18:46:59.157176"], ["updated_at", "2016-07-15 18:46:59.157176"]]
```

What is saved in my Database

```
   2.3.0 :001 > i = Image.last
  Image Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  "images".* FROM "images"  ORDER BY "images"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
 => #<Image id: 2, created_at: "2016-07-15 18:46:59", updated_at: "2016-07-15 18:46:59", user_id: 1, file_id: "117118", height: "564", width: "564", start_at: nil, end_at: "2016-08-10 19:46:00"> 
2.3.0 :002 >
```

Edit, requested Images model:

image.rb

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  has_many   :gallery_images, dependent: :destroy
  has_many   :galleries, through: :gallery_images

  has_many   :categories, through: :category_images
  has_many   :category_images

  attachment   :file, type: :image
  validates    :file, presence: true

  before_save  :set_dimensions, if: :file_id_changed?

  def set_dimensions
    fileio = file.to_io
    mm = if fileio.is_a?(StringIO)
           MiniMagick::Image.read(fileio.read)
         else
           MiniMagick::Image.read(file)
         end

    self.width  = mm.width
    self.height = mm.height
  end
end
```

Comment: write exit in create method and check it actually get the start_at value

Comment: Can you share your Image model code? Your params look correct, so I would suspect something going on within the model to prevent assignment.

Comment: Look at your insert: `INSERT INTO "images" ("file_id", "end_at", "user_id", "width", "height", "created_at", "updated_at")`. I don't see `start_at`. Do you? Check your permitted values.

Comment: @MarsAtomic Do you mean my image_params because here they are if not let me know: def image_params
    params.require(:image).permit(:file, :start_at, :end_at, category_ids: [])
end

Comment: Compare the incoming `"end_at"=>"10/08/2016 7:46 PM"` with the timestamp that ends up in the database `end_at: "2016-08-10 19:46:00"`. Then consider which month `23` is. Fix your date picker to send ISO 8601 timestamps back to your application so that there's no ambiguity about how the timestamps should be parsed.

Comment: @muistooshort has it right -- your datepicker is sending US-style slash-separated dates, but Rails (well, Ruby) doesn't like those. Your second date parameter is being ignored because it's invalid, not because of any code on your backend.

Comment: @muistooshort thanks, I see it now, if I'd picked a date with a day higher than 12 for end it wouldn't have saved there either, right?This is the first time I've really worked with time in an, so I'm still trying to figure out the best way to format it. Edit: added the last sentence

Comment: Yeah. I'm not familiar with the datepicker you're using but it should list the formatting options in its documentation. Your best bet is to use ISO8601 formats for all computer-to-computer communication and worry about formatting at the very edges of your application.